# Add the view controller in the TabBarController from within one of its viewControllers?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to iPhone/iPad Developer.

I am developing a application using `UITabBarController`.

I have created a tabbarcontroller class in which I have implemented a `UITabBarController` object through NIB file.

There are 4 tabs : LoginPage, Category Page, About Us Page, Setting Page.

I want to add logout tab in tabbarcontroller after login in Login Page by programmatically and when user will click to logout tab then it back to home/login screen and logout tab will eliminate.

So I need a code snippet to add `TabBarItem` in `UITabBarController` within its `UIViewController`.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

See [-[UITabBarController setViewControllers:animated:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a). On the iPhone, it will only display four tabs, but you should be able to remove the Login Page tab and put the Logout tab in its spot, then switch back after a logout.

Comment: for your reply. but i don't want to remove login page after login. I am loading User home view after login and i want add logout tab in tababrcontroller in login page class where i am checking UserName/Password.